# reCaptcha en Angular es intermitente

Tags: angular, recaptcha

Alguno me puede ayudar con mi problema....
Tengo en mi código un recaptcha de ng-recaptcha@10
Estoy usando la version 3, pero aveces me sale el icono del captcha, pero en su gran mayoría no.
Me podrías ayudar y mirar cómo solucionarlo, ya que si no aparece el icono, no me deja validarlo y me sale un error

El código lo tengo tal cual la documentacion

```
import { RECAPTCHA_SETTINGS, RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY, RecaptchaModule, RecaptchaSettings, RecaptchaV3Module } from 'ng-recaptcha';
    import { environment } from "../environments/environments";
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        RecaptchaV3Module,
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule,    
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY,
          useValue: environment.recaptcha.siteKey
        }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
    
    // AOT compilation support
    export function httpTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    }
```

[image: imagen con captcha]

[image: imagen sin captcha]

Comment: Cuando no sale imagino que habrá algún error en alguna parte, no? Deberías poder verlo en la consola depurando tu aplicación, de lo contrario solo podemos *adivinar* qué está pasando, y así no haremos nada más que perder el tiempo.

Comment: hice al cambio paraque miren la consola, no se ve ningun error si sale o no sale

Answer (score 0):

Con lo que muestras lo único que se me ocurre es que estés navegando por un dominio que no se ha agregado a tu cuenta de google recapcha.